# Call FunctionB if FunctionA isn't called again within 5 seconds

Tags: c++, timeout

I'm trying to write a function `TimeoutFunction`, which calls an other function e.x. `printf`, if the function `TimeoutFunction` wasn't called again within x seconds. If it was called again, the timeout should be resetted.
This code for example:

```
void TimeoutFunction(string MyString)
{
    //Wait 5 seconds and then call printf(MyString)
}

int main()
{
    TimeoutFunction("A");
    Sleep(4);
    TimeoutFunction("B");
    Sleep(6);
    TimeoutFunction("C");
    Sleep(10);
    TimeoutFunction("D");
    Sleep(2);
    TimeoutFunction("E");
}
```

would print:
`BCE` or at least `BC`

The Parameter `MyString` isn't necessary, but I added it to visualize it.

Comment: The question is not clear to me. It reminds me of handling arrow keys in the old text terminal days. Not sure, but what is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: If the TimeoutFunction is called once and then it isn't called in the next 5 seconds, it should call an other function e.x. printf. 
If within 5 seconds the TimeoutFunction is called again, the timeout is resetted to 5 seconds

Comment: Track the state via global vars

Comment: This sounds like an asynchronous call. You would need to package up arguments for that call. The C++ standard library provides some support for that via its futures, but I'm not sure whether they fit the bill (I haven't used them). At worst you can use `std::thread` directly. As noted by gj you need some static state to remember the time of last call.

Comment: But after the 5 seconds i need to call the function immediately. so I think I have to use `std::thread`, but I have no idea, how exactly

Comment: It may be difficult to provide a solution using standard C++. A platform-specific solution can though be easier to implement. What is the platform you are targeting ?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio in Windows

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some code which is not nice, but it works as i excepted

```
#include <thread>
#include <windows.h>

bool running;
unsigned long StartTime;
unsigned int WaitTime = 500;
const char* PrintString;
std::thread InternThread;

void MyPrint()
{
    while (running)
    {
        auto WaitedTime = GetTickCount() - StartTime;
        if (WaitedTime > WaitTime)
        {
            printf(PrintString);
            break;
        }
        Sleep(10);
    }
}


void TimeoutFunction(const char* MyString)
{
    StartTime = GetTickCount();
    PrintString = MyString;
    running = false;
    if (InternThread.joinable())
    {
        InternThread.join();
    }

    running = true;
    InternThread = std::thread(MyPrint);
}

int main()
{
    TimeoutFunction("A");
    Sleep(400);
    TimeoutFunction("B");
    Sleep(600);
    TimeoutFunction("C");
    Sleep(1000);
    TimeoutFunction("D");
    Sleep(200);
    TimeoutFunction("E");

    InternThread.join();
    return 0;
}
```

If someone has a nicer code, you're welcome.

Comment: Uhm, you need mutual exclusion for access of the shared variables.

Answer (score 0):

I've coded up equivalent hopefully portable code based on [your self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40279551/464581).

---

But first:

The technique you use in your own answer is smart, ensuring that either the main thread, or the worker thread, is accessing the common shared variables at any time. This was not my first idea of how to do this, i.e. it was not obvious to me, and it makes the code both simpler and more efficient than using a mutex for ensuring exclusive access to these variables. However, there are two synchronization problems with the way you've coded it up:

- The `bool` flag `running` needs to be made thread-safe.
  If the flag isn't made thread safe, then changes made in one thread (e.g. the main thread) may just make it out to some cache, but not all the way out to main memory, and likewise, the other thread's checking may just check a cache, and not directly main memory. Three possibilites are `std::atomic<bool>`, `std::atomic_flag` (less convenient but guaranteed lock free) and, third, using an extra `std::mutex`, e.g. combined with `std::unique_lock`.
- In the `TimeoutFunction` function the shared state updates need to made *after* joining the thread.
  For perfection the `GetTickCount` result then should be stored in a local variable before waiting on the thread to join.

---

For the standard C++ hopefully-portable code the `main` function is like this (doing almost exactly the same as in your posted answer):

*main.cpp:*

```
#include <stdio.h>                  // printf
#include <Delayed_action.hpp>       // my::(Delayed_action, sleep)

// Alternative to defining lots of small lambdas, a special case functor:
struct Print
{
    char const* s; 
    void operator()() const { printf( "%s", s ); }
    Print( char const* const a_literal ): s( a_literal ) {}
};

auto main()
    -> int
{
    using my::Delayed_action; using my::sleep;
    using namespace std::literals;  // ms

    Delayed_action da;
    da.set_action( Print{ "A" } );
    sleep( 400ms );
    da.set_action( Print{ "B" } );
    sleep( 600ms );
    da.set_action( Print{ "C" } );
    sleep( 1000ms );
    da.set_action( Print{ "D" } );
    sleep( 200ms );
    da.set_action( Print{ "E" } );
    da.wait_for_action_completed();
    printf( "\n" );
}
```

The two main abstractions here, that support reuse, are

- Putting the thread communication state in an object instead of globals.
- Parameterizing the action, instead of a hardcoded action.

The implementation of `Delayed_action` uses some general support stuff:

*cppx-class-kinds.hpp:*

```
#pragma once

namespace cppx {
    class No_copy
    {
    private:
        auto operator=( No_copy const& ) -> No_copy& = delete;
        No_copy( No_copy const& ) = delete;

    public:
        auto operator=( No_copy&& ) -> No_copy& { return *this; }
        No_copy() {}
        No_copy( No_copy&& ) {}
    };

    class No_move
    {
    private:
        auto operator=( No_move&& ) -> No_move& = delete;
        No_move( No_move&& ) = delete;

    public:
        auto operator=( No_move const& ) -> No_move& { return *this; }
        No_move() {}
        No_move( No_move const& ) {}
    };

    class No_copy_or_move
        : public No_copy
        , public No_move
    {};
}  // namespace cppx
```

*cppx-threading.hpp:*

```
#pragma once
#include <cppx-class-kinds.hpp>     // cppx::No_copy_or_move

#include <atomic>           // std::atomic
#include <chrono>           // std::chrono::milliseconds
#include <thread>           // std::thread

namespace cppx {
    namespace this_thread = std::this_thread;

    inline namespace std_aliases {
        using Milliseconds      = std::chrono::milliseconds;
        using Steady_clock      = std::chrono::steady_clock;
        using Time_point        = std::chrono::time_point<Steady_clock>;

        using Thread            = std::thread;    
    }

    inline void sleep( Milliseconds const duration )
    {
        this_thread::sleep_for( duration );
    }

    // Syntactic sugar for std::atomic_flag:
    // • boolean assignment
    // • default init to false.
    // std::atomic_flag is guaranteed lock free, as opposed to std::atomic<bool>.
    // Cost: there's no way to check the value except by setting it to true.
    class Atomic_flag
        : public No_copy_or_move
    {
    private:
        std::atomic_flag    flag_   = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT; // Initialized to false.

    public:
        void clear() { flag_.clear(); }

        auto test_and_set() -> bool
        {
            bool const previous_value = flag_.test_and_set();
            return previous_value;
        }

        void set() { test_and_set(); }

        void operator=( bool const should_be_set )
        {
            if( should_be_set ) set(); else clear();
        }

        Atomic_flag() {}
    };
}  // namespace cppx
```

With that wrapping and renaming of the standard library's things, the standard library based re-implementation of your idea, the `Delayed_action` class, can look like this:

*Delayed_action.hpp:*

```
#pragma once
#include <cppx-class-kinds.hpp> // cppx::No_copy_or_move
#include <cppx-threading.hpp>   // cppx::(Atomic_flag, sleep)

#include <functional>           // std::(function, ref)
#include <utility>              // std::move

namespace my {
    using namespace cppx::std_aliases;
    using namespace std::literals;

    using cppx::Atomic_flag;
    using cppx::No_copy_or_move;
    using cppx::sleep;
    using std::move;
    using std::ref;

    using Action = std::function<void()>;

    class Delayed_action
        : public No_copy_or_move
    {
    private:
        struct Parameters
        {
            Atomic_flag     run;
            Action          action;
            Time_point      when;
        };

        static void polling( Parameters& parameters )
        {
            for( ;; )
            {
                if( not parameters.run.test_and_set() )
                {
                    return;
                }
                else if( Steady_clock::now() >= parameters.when )
                {
                    parameters.action();
                    return;
                }
                sleep( 10ms );
            }
        }

    private:
        Parameters  parameters_;
        Thread      worker_;

        void join_worker_thread()
        {
            if( worker_.joinable() )
            {
                worker_.join();
            }
        }

        void end_worker_thread()
        {
            parameters_.run = false;
            join_worker_thread();
        }

    public:
        static auto default_delay() -> Milliseconds { return 500ms; }

        void set_action( Action action, Milliseconds const delay = default_delay() )
        {
            Time_point const when = Steady_clock::now() + delay;
            end_worker_thread();
            parameters_.action = move( action );
            parameters_.when = when;
            parameters_.run = true;
            worker_ = Thread( &polling, ref( parameters_ ) );
        }

        void wait_for_action_completed() { join_worker_thread(); }

        ~Delayed_action() { end_worker_thread(); }

        Delayed_action() {}

        Delayed_action( Action action, Milliseconds const delay = default_delay() )
        {
            set_action( move( action ), delay );
        }
    };
}  // namespace my
```